# C++ - Convert FILE* to CHAR*

Tags: c++, file, char

I found a C++ source file which calculates expressions from a command line argument (argv[1]), however I now want to change it to read a file.

```
double Utvardering(char* s) {
srcPos = s;
searchToken();
return PlusMinus();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if (argc > 1) {
    FILE* fFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    double Value = Utvardering(fopen(argv[1], "r"));
    cout << Value << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " FILE" << endl;
}
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

However the Utvardering function requires a char* parameter. How can I convert the data read from a file, fopen to a char*?

Comment: Kind of funny, but I suspect Utvardering() should be the swedish Utvärdering(), which means Evaluation(). Not often you see swedish words in code, and especially not on SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function fopen just opens a file. To get a string from there, you need to read the file. There are different ways to to this. If you know the max size of your string in advance, this would do:

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 1024;
char buf[MAX_SIZE];
if (!fgets(buf, MAX_SIZE, fFile) {
  cerr << "Read error";
  exit(1);
}
double Value = Utvardering(buf);
```

Note: this method is typical for C, not for C++. If you want more idiomatic C++ code, you can use something like this (instead of FILE and fopen):

```
ifstream in;    
in.open(argv[1]); 
if (!in) { /* report an error */ }
string str;
in >> str;
```

Comment: You can declare MAX_SIZE as a constant either in the body of the function, or outside, as a global constant. Usually the less clutter in the global namespace, the better, so just put it inside the main function. I've updated the example, see above.

Comment: The first example doesn't set it to char *, any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain, what do you mean by "doesn't set it to char*"? For debugging, you can add this line before call to the Utvardering: printf("%s\n", buf);  to make sure the buf contains the same string as your file.

Comment: I get this error:
123 C:\Dev-Cpp\Projects\TestLang\test1.cpp cannot convert `char*' to `FILE*' for argument `3' to `char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)'

Comment: The 3rd argument to fgets should be fFile. Do you declare and initialize it as FILE* fFile = fopen(argv[1], "r"); ?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [fread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs(VS.71).aspx) function to read data from the FILE* into a buffer. Send that buffer into Utvardering().

Comment: remember to fclose() it afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what "Utvardering" expects, or how it's using the information.

There are two possibilities -

1) Utvardering may be defined using char*, but expecting a FILE* (in effect, treating char* like void*).  I've seen this before, even though it's pretty awful practice.  In that case, just cast fFile to char* and pass it in.

2) Utvardering may be expecting a null terminated string (char*) as input.  If you're using fopen like this, you can use [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) to read the file contents into a buffer (char[]), and pass it to your function that takes a char*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to write code to read the file into a character array and pass that to `Utvardering`.

Just passing the return value of `fopen` will cause the address of the opaque data structure pointed to by that pointer to be passed to `Utvardering`. `Utvardering` will happily treat those bytes as character data when they are not. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

Good example of reading data from a file here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/
then pass the buffer to your function